# How to get ComponentContext from BundleContext in OSGi

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle

I have an OSGi bundle with multiple components, I want to activate/deactivate components from other components in same bundle.

I got `BundleContext` from below code:

```
import aQute.bnd.annotation.component.Activate;
import aQute.bnd.annotation.component.Component;
import aQute.bnd.annotation.component.Deactivate;

@Activate
public void activate(Map<String, Object> properties) {

    BundleContext bundleContext = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(MyComponent.class).getBundleContext();
}
```

But how can I get the `ComponentContext` so that I can do `enableComponent`  or `disableComponent`?

Comment: @Golden Gate : I approved your edit . I'd like to point out that if you're going to remove names from posts (which is good), you should also remove "Thanks", "Hi", etc. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) for the discussion, if you're interested.

Comment: You might want to switch to the standard OSGi annotations since the bnd annotations that inspired the standardized annotations are going to be deprecated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply inject the ComponentContext. You can then get the BundleContext as well as the config properties from it.

```
@Activate
public void activate(ComponentContext context)
```

Comment: You can also put all the arguments on the activate method: void activate(Map<String, Object> properties, ComponentContext context,BundleContext bc).